# how the best way to get double from String "1,000.0" in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a String to Number - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097332/convert-a-string-to-number-java)

```
String s="1,000.0";
```

how can I get double value from this String?

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en_US"));

    try {
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("1,000.0"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Handle this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [DecimalFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29).

Answer (score 0):

i think this example works:

[String to Double - Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Convertstringtodouble.htm)