# How to format 1000000 to 1,000,000 etc

Tags: java

How do you convert number values to include dots or commas in Java? I tried searching the web, but I didn't find a good answer. Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format a String number to have commas and round?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round)

Comment: Look at this answer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097332/convert-a-string-to-number-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `java.text.NumberFormat` class will do this, using the appropriate separator for your locale.  Example:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(1000000));

==>1,000,000
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me out :) I already found the number forma thingy, but I didn't know how to use it because I'm new to java :)

Answer (score 6):

There's a class called `NumberFormat` which will handle printing numbers in a certain format and also parsing a `String` representing a number into an actual `Number`.

`DecimalFormat` is a concrete subclass of `NumberFormat`, you can use `DecimalFormat` to e.g. format numbers using comma as a grouping separator:

```
NumberFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
```

You can also use `DecimalFormat` for currency formatting.

Similarly, `DateFormat` handles parsing and printing dates.

The javadocs are here: [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
new DecimalFormat("#,###,###").format(1000000);
```

Comment: You only need `"#,###"`. This will set it up to automatically group everything in 3's. +1 for giving a working format string.