# how to retrieve currency format values from JformattedTextfield

Tags: java, swing, textfield, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

I have this problem where I am trying to retrieve and  pass calculated values to JformattedTextfield, I know  1,500.00 can not be accepted by Float due to the jformattedTextfield (**,**). Is there a way to bypass this issue ?

```
 private void SellButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
      float foreign , sellingRate, localAmount;
            try{
            DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel)p1.getModel();
            int i = p1.getSelectedRow();
            String s1=dtm.getValueAt(i,2).toString();
            txt_rate.setText(s1);
      }catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select Currency First");
      }
            foreign =  Float.parseFloat(txt_select.getText());
            sellingRate =  Float.parseFloat(txt_rate.getText());
            localAmount = foreign / sellingRate;
            txt_amount.setValue(localAmount);
        }
```

Error Message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,500.00"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
```

[image: under thousand unite]

I can calulate numbers under {**1,000**}

Expected result
[image: Expected result]

Comment: crazy FX volatility for Rate in JTable

Comment: int i = p1.getSelectedRow(); should be wrapped in all cases into if (i > -1), better with SelectionMode to SINGLE

Comment: works for me with JFormattedTextField with number instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to let the user input the currency with a thousands separator? At least to all applications I have seen and developed so far, this is very uncommon.

Usually you only use it for display purposes, not for input. So the user would enter `1000` and you'll display it as `1,000.00` by formatting the value by `NumberFormat.format()`.

If you really want the input like that, it should be treated as a `String` and then be parsed by `NumberFormat.parse()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097332/convert-a-string-to-number-java).