# Get EditTextValue and parse it into a decimal with only one digit for integer part

Tags: android, numbers, android-edittext, decimal

I'm having an issue when I get a whole number from an EditText and try to  change that to a decimal so I can use it for calculations. Could someone explain how to do this?

For Example.  if someone was to enter 120 into the EditText and I got the integer from it, how would I then change that integer of 120 into 1.20  and continue calculations with it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_ID);
String numberAsString = myEditText.getText().toString();

double myDecimal;
try {
    myDecimal = Double.parseDouble(numberAsString);
    if (myDecimal >= 10)
    {
        int digits = 1 + (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(myDecimal));
        myDecimal = myDecimal / ((Math.pow((double)10, ((double)digits) - 1)));
        System.out.println(myDecimal);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //handle exeption
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks but now how to I change it into a decimal to do further calculations with

Comment: Well, now, variable myDecimal contains your double, you can do wathever math calculation with it. If your aim is to change the format into the EditText, i'm affraid there is no way to do that

Comment: I mean, if someone was to enter 120 into myEditText how would I then change that into 1.20 ?

Comment: faster and better way. (not sure about the -1) you'll need to check this by yourself

Comment: This was a great help thanks :) I tried to divide it by 100 before all this but that didn't work but you have made it work :) so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int three = Integer.parse("3");
```

I know you can use this to parse a string into an integer, there is probably a parse method in double aswell!

Check this also :
[Convert a String to Double - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097332/convert-a-string-to-double-java)

+1 to anthony for answering 1 minute before me haha

Comment: I would also for the user to input decimal by adding the inputType attribute and set it to numberDecimal. and put the previous statement in a try catch because it might throw : java.lang.NumberFormatException.

Comment: check my answer i added a try catch

Comment: thanks but now how to I change it into a decimal to do further calculations with

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the contents from your EditText as a string, and from there you can parse it into an integer. This is done like so:

```
 int wholeNum = Integer.parseInt(yourEditText.getText().toString());
```